# Changing SQL VARCHAR2 date to another date format

Tags: sql, time, format, utc, sentence

I have a date (stored as a VARCHAR2) in a database with the format:

```
20090123_163842.865
yyyyMMdd_hhmmss.ttt
```

and I want to make a SQL sentence to obtain:

```
23/01/2009 16:38:42,865
dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss,ttt
```

MY objective is to add it manually (I know that data can be exported from database, and imported into Excel, but I want to do it manually) to Excel as a recognizable Date.

How should my SQL sentence be?

I have tried to to it by:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP(my_time_utc, 'YYYYMMDD_HH24MISS.FF3') from myTable
```

but I am only able to obtain:

```
2009-01-23 16:38:42.865
```

Thanks

Comment: Never, ever store dates in VARCHAR2 columns!

Comment: I know it, but I had no opportunity to take part in the database design when the database was designed :( .

Comment: If you can, refactor the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It never ceases to amaze me how many people confuse these operations.

First you need to convert the varchar 'fake date' to a real date: use `to_date` for this.
Then you need to convert the date to a varchar for presentation: use `to_char` for this.

```
select to_char(to_date(column, 'yyyyMMdd_hhmmss.ttt'), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss,ttt')
from your_table;
```

should do what you want.

Comment: TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(my_time_utc, 'YYYYMMDD_HH24MISS.FF3'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,FF3')

Answer (score 1):

When oracle retrieve a date field from database and **show it to you a cast implicit conversion is made**. The format pattern for this conversion is set in oracle configuration. [Quoting oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm):

> The default date format for an Oracle date value is derived from the
>   NLS_DATE_FORMAT and NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE initialization parameters

- If you perform query from Excel, your actual query is enougth because excel know date format and is able to read from Oracle with out problems.
- If you do a copy-paste from your screen results to excel, then you should cast back date to varchar with your desired format or, of course, change oracle configuration to match your locales.